# Splitpane JavaFX: Text rendering on same level on both panes

Tags: java, javafx

I am building a speech to text application. I am using a splitpane to display it.
The left pane displays the dynamically changing speech to text information.
The right pane displays a "yes/no" fixed text for each sentence spoken on left pane on the same level.

To ensure that the "Yes/NO" appears at the exact same level as the sentence on left pane I am adding the text on both the left and right panes to respective Hboxes(Splitpane_left_hbox(Speech to text sentence) and Splitpane_right_hbox ("Yes/No") ) whenever a new sentence is spoken.

The left and right boxes are placed in left_Vbox and right_vbox for the vertical rendering of speech to text sentences.

I am measuring the height of the Splitpane_left_hbox(containing the variable width speech to text sentences) to assign the same height to the Hbox on right. So that when a new sentence appears both the texts on Splitpane_left_hbox and Splitpane_right_hbox appear at the same level on a new line.

ISSUES:

1. The Splitpane_left_hbox.getHeight() returns 0.0 even though there is text in it.
2. This prevents me from setting a value to the Splitpane_left_hbox to position them at the same level.

Questions:

1. How do I get the final height of the Splitpane_left_hbox after the speech-to-text text has been added to it?
2. Is there a more efficient way to make these texts appear at the same level on both the panes?

FXML file:

```
<SplitPane fx:id="split_pane" dividerPositions="0.49613899613899615" prefHeight="497.0" prefWidth="1040.0">
     <items>
        <ScrollPane prefViewportHeight="341.0" prefViewportWidth="512.0">
           <content>
              <VBox fx:id="split_pane_1_Vbox" prefHeight="494.0" prefWidth="513.0">
                 <children>
                    <HBox fx:id="split_pane_1_hbox" fillHeight="false">
                       <children>
                          <Text fx:id="text_1" />
                       </children>
                    </HBox>
                 </children>
              </VBox>
           </content>
        </ScrollPane>
        <ScrollPane prefViewportHeight="341.0" prefViewportWidth="520.0">
           <content>
              <VBox fx:id="split_pane_2_Vbox" prefHeight="496.0" prefWidth="523.0">
                 <children>
                    <HBox fx:id="split_pane_2_hbox" prefHeight="300.0" prefWidth="200.0" />
                    <children>
                       <Text fx:id="text_2" />
                   </children>
              </VBox>
           </content>
        </ScrollPane>
     </items>
  </SplitPane>
```

Java method:

```
void addFinalText(String sentence) {



    Text text_1 = new Text(sentence.trim());
    text_1.setFont(Font.font(null, FontWeight.MEDIUM, textSize));
    double[] dividerPositions = split_pane.getDividerPositions();



    double split_pane_width = split_pane.getPrefWidth();
    double single_pane_width = dividerPositions[0] * split_pane_width;
    text_1.setWrappingWidth(single_pane_width);


    Text text_2 = new Text();
    text_2.setFont(Font.font(null, FontWeight.MEDIUM, textSize));




    Text text = new Text();
    text.setText(sentence.trim() +  " ");
    text.setFont(Font.font(null, FontWeight.MEDIUM, textSize));


    if (sentence.contains("hi")) {

        text_2.setText("Yes" + "\n");
        text_2.setFill(Color.RED);
        text_1.setFill(Color.RED);
    }
    else {
        text_2.setText("No" + "\n");
    }

    HBox left_hbox = new HBox();
    left_hbox.getChildren().add(text_1);
    double leftHboxHeight = left_hbox.getHeight();

    HBox right_hbox = new HBox();
    right_hbox.setHeight(leftHboxHeight);
    right_hbox.getChildren().add(text_2);

    right_hbox.getChildren().add(text_2);
    left_hbox.getChildren().add(text_1);

}
```

[App screenshot:](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SHnl9.jpg)

I am new to JavaFx. Thanks in advance.
        `

Comment: A `GridPane` might be a better layout for you instead of the `SplitPane`. The `GridPane` can ensure everything is lined up correctly without needing to do all the manual measurements.

Answer (score 0):

Nodes are not positioned before the next layout pass. This layout pass happens sometime after method returns. It would be better to use a `Pane` for the Yes/No text and bind the`layoutY` property of those nodes to the `layoutY` property. Just make sure the vertical alignment of the text that is added to the right is correct.

#### Simplified example

```
@Override
public void start(Stage primaryStage) {
    VBox left = new VBox();
    Pane right = new Pane();
    
    Button button = new Button("Add");
    
    HBox hbox = new HBox(left, right, button);
    button.setOnAction(new EventHandler<ActionEvent>() {
        private int count = 1;
        
        private final StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder("1");
        
        @Override
        public void handle(ActionEvent event) {
            Text text = new Text(builder.toString());
            Text yesNo = new Text(count % 2 == 0 ? "Yes" : "No");
            yesNo.setTextOrigin(VPos.TOP);
            
            HBox container = new HBox(text);
            
            left.getChildren().add(container);
            left.getChildren().add(text);
            right.getChildren().add(yesNo);
            yesNo.layoutYProperty().bind(container.layoutYProperty());
            
            count++;
            builder.append('\n');
            for (int i = 0; i < count; i++) {
                builder.append('1');
            }
        }
    
    });
    
    Scene scene = new Scene(hbox, 400, 400);
    primaryStage.setScene(scene);
    primaryStage.show();
}
```

---

Note that this won't synchronize scrolling for both `ScrollPane`s. I recommend using a `GridPane` and adding the text to the same `ScrollPane` instead.